# Maven Failure to find com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.3

Tags: maven, proxy, jar, dependencies, maven-3

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11
- Maven 3.6.3

I've a maven project and working behind a proxy, so I configured in settings.xml and I proved with a profile with some repositories and without any profile.

Repositories I've tried but something must be wrong

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

**settings.xml**

```
<proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>{iAf/vSQegd4HPDkp1yBqXZvGPGZgikDH+j6IqwOdu5I=}</password>
    <host>rproxy.domain.com</host>
    <port>3128</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

**Error log**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project doit: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project:doit:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project doit: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.projects:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced
...
```

Comment: The dependency you're looking for seems to be here [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri/2.3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri/2.3.3) and without other mentions or that page, it should be available on main _Maven_ repository. Are you should that the good maven repo is contacted ?

Comment: I looked at the url you gave me and I notice it is type pom, and I go step further.
Now I got another error Failed to initialize ear modules: Unknown artifact type[zip] for relea
se-documentation